# Wicket: How to create a dynamic url (e.g. for images)

Tags: wicket

I am just wondering how I can specify a dynamic url for an image src in apache wicket.
I just thought about something like 
new StaticResourceReference("images/buttons/" + filename+ ".gif") 
but I cannot find such a class or apporoach. There seem to be ugly workarounds, like the ones mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512510/wicket-dynamic-image-url).

I really can't imagine that a popular framework like wicket doesn't have an easy support for dynamic relative/absolute urls (also think about external ressources/urls..)

Did I missed something?
Thank you!

Comment: Is the image created dynamically (rendered through some Java code) or do you want to create an URL for a resource in your war?

Comment: The latter. It's a static resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+load+an+external+image) document describes two possiblities how to do it in wicket:
I am not 100% happy with the approaches, but it seems to work.

Comment: @Doc adjusted. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want a dynamic filename, try something like this:

html:

```
<img wicket:id="wicketimage"/>
```

code to support your html page:

```
WebMarkupContainer markup = new WebMarkupContainer( "wicketimage" );
markup.add( new AttributeModifier( "src", true, new Model<String>( "images/buttons/filename.gif" ) ) );    
add( markup );
```